# Plotly 4.5.2 update broke my rectangular heatmap

Tags: r, plotly

I've updated plotly package, and now I am having issues with my heatmap.

```
m <- matrix(rnorm(8), nrow = 4, ncol = 2)
plot_ly(
  x = c("a", "b"), y = c("c", "d", "e", "f"),
  z = m, type = "heatmap"
)
```

gives me an error:

```
Error: Variables must be length 1 or 4.
Problem variables: 'x'
```

Any idea on how to fix it? Adding empty labels did not help. The only solution that actually worked was repeating vector

```
x = c("a", "b", "a", "b")
```

or

```
x = c("a", "b", "b", "b")
```

However I would like to have a more neat solution, as with a bigger dataset it could get messy.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is a bug, but specifying as many variables as `max(dim(m))` will fix your code.

```
set.seed(123)
m <- matrix(rnorm(8), nrow = 4, ncol = 2)
dim(m)
plot_ly(
  x = c(letters[1:2], "NA", "NA"), y = letters[3:6],
  z = m, type = "heatmap")
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

IF you update to 4.5.5.9000 this bug is already solved.

```
devtools::install_github("ropensci/plotly")
```